# Cordova/AngularJS State Reload Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working on a Cordova/AngularJS mobile application and I'm struggling to get my current state to reload with new data.

Please note that this is NOT an Ionic Framework application.

The part of my application that is affected by this is when I have to present questions for the user to answer. There are 2 question types, `select` and `draganddrop`. For each question type there is a controller, namely `selectCtrl` and `draganddropCtrl` and of course views tied to each controller.

The problem arises when questions of the same 'type' appear consecutively. I have to reload the current state and controller with the new values and options for the new question.

I have tried everything that is available on the interwebs. Including:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $state.$current.params, { 
                  reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true 
                });
```

and..

```
$state.reload() //although I hear there are known issues with this one
```

and even the old fashioned..

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

What all of these do is that they just send the user to my `welcomeCtrl` which is the first controller that gets loaded after the  user logs in.

It doesn't make any sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: $state.go('<state>') didn't work ?

Comment: @Abhi That's the first method that I tried and no it doesn't work. It just sits there without refreshing.

Comment: Can you try the application on a browser directly and not webview - see if it gives any error on console.

Comment: @kingLoosh Did you get any solution? I too have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, it should work

```
$state.go($state.current.name, $stateParams, {reload: true, reloadOnSearch: true});
```

Also you have to pass state name in transitionTo call instead of $state.current, but above $state.go works for me.

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current.name, $state.$current.params, { 
                  reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true 
                });
```

Comment: thanks but this still doesn't work. Same behaviour as the others I've tried.